# Creating Custom Base controller for capturing query string values. GOOD or BAD?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This question is basically to know and justify whether what I am doing is a good practice or if there are any other ways to achieve the solution for the problem.

Here is the problem....
* I have an MVC application with many controllers and action methods. Customers will be accessing different action methods from different sources (google, bing, third party sites) adding a query string signature at the end.

* Since I dont want to check the querystring value in every action of the controller. I created a new controller "BaseController.cs" which inherits from the MVC Controller class. And implements the following code. All the application controllers will inherit from the BaseController.

```
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
       public BaseController():base()
       { 
            string siteReference = HttpContext.Request["ref"];
       }
    }
```

I am requesting the experts of MVC to suggest better ways. Thanks in advance.

-KK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a less obstrussive way to do it, you can use a global action filter to do the same without having to use a base controller, and you favor composition over inheritance.

```
  public class GetQueryString: IActionFilter, IMvcFilter
    {

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            string siteReference = filterContext.HttpContext.Request["ref"];
        }


        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
        {

        }


        public bool AllowMultiple
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public int Order
        {
            get { return Filter.DefaultOrder; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And why would you favor Compsition over Inheritance? Mind explaining the reasons one is better?

Comment: Inheritance increases cohesion, composition doesnt, he could easily replace the action filter without breaking anything else, because his controller wont even know about of its existence.